# How to start an Activity when a url is requested in a browser

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi i want to open an activity when a url is called.url is (http://riteshmehandiratta.appspot.com).here is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.familygraph7"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".FamilyActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:label="Hello Wordl"
        android:name=".FamilyUser" >
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.riteshmehandiratta.appspot.com" /> 
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

but when i tried to open the Url in browser its not opening my activity.please suggest the way that how to start an activity when a particular url is called.

Comment: do you want to launch an activity when the user has typed an URL in his/her browser and searched for it? or do you want to launch a browser act. with a specific url from your activity?

Comment: url is called from where?? Please rephrase your question a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the BROWSABLE category to your `<activity>` in the manifest:

```
  <activity android:label="Hello Wordl" android:name=".FamilyUser" >
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.riteshmehandiratta.appspot.com" /> 
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```